# How can I use my IOS app without codesign on my iphone?

Tags: ios, flutter

I am pretty new to IOS development and I am trying to just use the app personally first on my own. I found this site:

https://www.diawi.com/

Which let you use your app on your phone without all the hassle. The only thing is that I am getting this error when trying to upload my .ipa file.

```
Missing embedded mobileprovision
```

I am using https://www.codemagic.io/ to build the .ipa file from my project, because I have no Mac on hand. This is the command it is executing:

```
flutter build ios --release --no-codesign --split-debug-info=/
```

As you can see I am using --no-codesign in the flutter build, because you need to have an certificate from apple to use codesign. However, I am not interested, at least for now, to use my app commercially. I just want to use it for myself on my iphone.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Btw, I only use windows.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a signed IPA to install it on your device. For that you need to have an Apple Developer Account.

In my case I do not use Codemagic but [Odevio](https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI) a similar tool. To be able to test the app on my device I do the following (after setting Odevio up) :

```
odevio build start --build-type ad-hoc
odevio build ipa
```

and then you just have to send the link you get to your iPhone to install the app on your device.

Or if you want to test in TestFlight run

```
odevio build start --build-type publication
```

and then in App Store Connect publish your test flight app.

I suppose there is such a functionality in codemagic too.

Answer (score 0):

You can install only signed apps on a physical device. Doesn't matter if it's yours or someone else app.

This makes possible for Apple to cancel your certificate and delete the app from any device in a case the app is breaking a rules of Apple.

Apple has a free option for developers with Apple ID. Just go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Left pane, bottom menu tools bar and click "+" button.

More details from Apple website [source](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)

> You can learn how to develop apps for Apple platforms for free without
> enrolling. With just an Apple ID, you can access Xcode, software
> downloads, documentation, sample code, forums, and Feedback Assistant,
> as well as test your apps on devices. If you don’t already have an
> Apple ID, you can create one here. To distribute apps, join the Apple
> Developer Program.